# Does $a^n=b^n$ and $a^m = b^m$ implies $a=b$ in an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

More specific, we have an integral domain $D$, $a,b\in D$ such that $a^n=b^n$ and $a^m=b^m$ for two positive integers $m,n$ that are relative primes. I need to prove that $a = b$. Also, my teacher insist that this could be proved without the exponent laws, since we haven't proved them in general for rings.

Comment: what are the exponent laws?

Comment: Use Bezout's identity for $n$ and $m$. Only multiplicative monoid is needed.

Comment: sorry, that's how i commonly refer to $x^n*x^m =x^{n+m}$ and $(x^n)^m=x^{nm}$

Comment: The integral domain assumption is unnecessary.

Comment: @GalPorat No, this is not unnecessary. In the ring $M_n(K)$ we can take $A=0$ and $B\neq 0$ a nilpotent matrix with $B^n=B^m=0$.

Comment: Another duplicate is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878548/if-am-bm-and-an-bn-show-that-a-b?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: You are right of course, early morning sloppiness on my part :)